# Create simple autofill function in C detecting on screen text strings

Tags: c, text-files, autofill

I've made a very simple program in C that will first ask me to fill in a N*N matrix. Let's say that N is 5, so that means I have to fill in 25 spots. Usually I will input something like 1, 2, 3... 24, 25. This becomes quite tiring after a few runs. Instead of modifying the program I've made to fill in the matrix with a loop, I would like to use some function that would "detect" or "react" to whats printed on screen.

If I'm not mistaken, I'll have to mess around with files. I know that whatever one types while running the program is basically treated as a file called stdin (standard input), so I believe that what comes up on the screen is treated as another file.

For instance, when printf comes up:

```
print("Type the desired value:   ");
scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
```

I would like to have this function that I want to make to detect that "Type the desired value" has been printed on screen, and then I want it to automatically modify the "stdin" file that I've been talking about and "type in" e.g. 17.

I hope that I'm being clear. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does that mean you cannot change this program, but want another program (written by you) to fill in the text?

Comment: Exactly. Actually I can change the program, but I would like to challenge myself and assume I can't. I would like to add a new function to the program I'm making that will do what I mentioned that works in parallel to the remaining functions.

Comment: Can you use bi-directional pipes?  Not sure how you want to run these 2 applications.